# Image expanding out of div on iPad mobile Safari

Tags: css, mobile-safari

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="main">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/180x180">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.outer {
    /* Outer Container With Padding */
    background: red;
    padding: 60px;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.inner {
    /* Bottom padding for fluid div with 2:1 ratio */
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.main {
    /* container for the image */
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.main img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why the image is stretching beyond its container div. It works fine in everything except for mobile safari and chrome for iPad. Running the latest version of iOS.

Open below on iPad to see:

http://jsfiddle.net/svja8rgv/3/

Comment: Did you try: in .main img  position: absolute; ?

Comment: Things you can do to find out what is wrong: Run CSS Browser Tests for CSS1, CSS2, CSS3 (Acid 2 Browsertest and Acid3 Browsertest) or try to build the wrong behavior on a browser where it doesn't occur.

Comment: Thanks. Absolutely positioning the image worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to set the positioning of the image itself to `position: absolute`.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="main">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/180x180">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.outer {
    /* Outer Container With Padding */
    background: red;
    padding: 60px;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.inner {
    /* Bottom padding for fluid div with 2:1 ratio */
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.main {
    /* container for the image */
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.main img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```